# Calling model from codeigniter library shows error

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, static-libraries

Hello I have created a library `Auth.php` in `application/libraries` to authenticate if the current user is logged in or not. So my controller is :

```
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$this->load->library('Auth');
$auth = new Auth;
$user_id = $auth->authenticate($session_data);
```

And the library :

```
class Auth{
    function authenticate($vars){

        $CI =&get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('adminmodels/login_model');

        $username = $vars['username'];
        $password = $vars['password'];
        $user_id = $vars['user_id'];;
        $user_type = $vars['user_type'];

        $check_login = $this->login_model->login($username,$password); //Line 14

        if($check_login){
            $user_id = $user_id;
        }else{
            $user_id = 0;
        }

        return $user_id;
   }
}
```

But it is showing error like :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Auth::$login_model
>
> Filename: libraries/Auth.php
>
> Line Number: 14

Whats wrong I am doing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While correct generally, in CI you should call the library like this, not with the `new` keyword:

```
$this->load->library('Auth');
$user_id = $this->auth->authenticate($session_data);
```

Also, since you assigned the global CI object to a variable, you can't use `$this` to refer to it:

```
    $check_login = $this->login_model->login($username,$password); //Line 14
```

should be:

```
    $check_login = $CI->login_model->login($username,$password); //Line 14
```

(since you loaded the model there: `$CI->load->model('adminmodels/login_model');` )

Answer (score 0):

Inside Codeigniter library file, you cannot load any model, config, or any external library using $this by pass without CI instance object/variable

For your case in Auth.php at line 14, you are wrong :

```
$check_login = $this->login_model->login($username,$password); //Line 14
```

It should be like this (if access from internal function only) :

```
$check_login = $CI->login_model->login($username,$password); //Line 14
```

Or, if access from any functions in the Auth class :

```
$check_login = $this->CI->login_model->login($username,$password); //Line 14
```

But first, you must make CI intance object in your construct function like this :

```
$this->CI =&get_instance();
$this->CI->load->model('adminmodels/login_model');
```

before you action in second alternative above.

May help you...
Thanks